# Azure Purview support for Delta Format sink in Data flow of ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-purview

I was recently exploring Azure Purview and was trying to push lineage information from ADF to Azure purview. However, it seems when we sink data in Delta Format using dataflow in ADF (Which is a inline format for data flow), it doesn't capture the lineage information. Whereas, it captures the lineage information when sinking using "dataset" in "Parquet" format. Is it that I am missing something here or its a bug or a feature that needs to be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Lake lineage from ADF data flow is not supported in Azure Purview right now. This is a known limitation and we are working to get it released. There is no ETA at this time.